# Jenkins GIT plug in - not pulling right code

Tags: git, jenkins

I’m having a problem getting Jenkins to pull the right code. The project is set up to pull develop branch. (Previously the project was set to trigger on commit to master, but now I've set it to develop.)

The build says that it is pulling origin/develop, and the GIT commit number is correct, as screenshot below shows:

[image]

However, when I look at the code in the Jenkins workspace on the server, it is NOT the correct code. I’m unsure what branch it is but assume it is master.

I have no idea why this is happening – can anyone advise please?

Comment: Look at `git log` and `git branch` on the server to find out what commit/branch it's on.

Comment: agree, login to the server and do a `git status` on the workspace for this project. you should also wipe the workspace just in case. is it possible you have multiple branches specified for polling?

Comment: 1) Only develop is specified.
2) Jenkins is set to wipe workspace. Also, I have manually deleted it myself on the server.
3) If I do git status in the workspace it says it's not on any branch...

git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
A few files listed here.

Comment: Interestingly the files which are listed as changed are all the ones with a diff to master branch. (I found this by raising a PR from dev to master, and the 5 files listed are the 5 files which show under "changes to be commited:" on the server.

So it's as if it's pulled develop, then pulled master and updated those files or something??

Comment: I think I've fixed it...
1) I removed all local changes from the server directory (git status now doesn't work as it's not a git repo)
2) Now do a build. It pulls latest code and git status now says not on any branch, and no untracked changes

It seems that wiping the directory/workspace doesn't seem to truely wipe it and it seems to remember that there are local changes?? Seems very bizzare - have either of you ever come across this?

Comment: @PB1990 I've seen where the workspace gets out of sync with the branch but not had the problem of .git hanging around after a wipe. Especially when I do a wipe from the workspace Jenkins page versus the wipe workspace before build.